# Load new data each time the same angular component get called

Tags: angular

I have three links in the sidemenu which redirect the user to the same Angular component.

If I click one of these links the first time, the right data is loaded, because the component wasn't loaded before. After that the component is already loaded and if I now click another link, the new data don't get loaded.

How can I change the behavior of the component that each time when I click one of these three links, other data get loading?

I have searched for possible solutions but I haven't found anything that helped.

Comment: Everyone has to guess at what the problem is since you haven't posted any code.  It's impossible to answer a code question without seeing your code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In have done it in the meantime. 

I intialised an Observable on the URL that detects all URL-changes. So I can load the required data for every page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.